# populate my many-to-many relation in Django

Tags: python, css, django, django-models, many-to-many

I am new in Django and Python. There are three models in my study project among a number of others:

models.py

```
class Protein(models.Model):
    protein_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    taxonomy = models.ForeignKey(
        Taxonomy, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    length = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    access = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.protein_id

class Pfam(models.Model):
    domain_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    domain_description = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.domain_id

class Domain(models.Model):
    pfam = models.ForeignKey(Pfam, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    stop = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    protein = models.ManyToManyField(
        Protein, related_name='domains', through='ProteinDomainLink')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pfam.domain_id

class ProteinDomainLink(models.Model):
    protein = models.ForeignKey(Protein, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Class Domain has ManyToMany field, linked to class Protein through class ProteinDomainLink.

There are three csv files to retrieve data from, and my populate script looks like:

populate_data.py

```
data_sequences_file = '../..source_file_1';
pfam_descriptions_file = '../..source_file_2';
data_set_file = '../..source_file_3';

pfam = defaultdict(list)
domains = defaultdict(list)
proteins = defaultdict(list)

... 

with open(pfam_descriptions_file) as pfam_descriptions_csv_file:
    pfam_descriptions_csv_reader = csv.reader(
        pfam_descriptions_csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in pfam_descriptions_csv_reader:
        pfam[row[0]]=row[1:2]

with open(data_set_file) as data_set_csv_file:
    data_set_csv_reader = csv.reader(data_set_csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in data_set_csv_reader:
        domains[row[5]] = row[4:5]+row[6:8]
        proteins[row[0].strip()] = row[1:2]+row[8:9]

pfam_rows = {}
domain_rows = {}
proteins_rows = {}

...

for domain_id, entry in pfam.items():
    row = Pfam.objects.create(
        domain_id=domain_id,
        domain_description=entry[0]
    )
    row.save()
    pfam_rows[domain_id] = row

for protein_id, entry in proteins.items():
    row, created = Protein.objects.get_or_create(
        protein_id=protein_id,
        taxonomy=taxonomy_rows[entry[0]],
        length=entry[1],
    )
    row.save()
    proteins_rows[protein_id] = row

#That's my question:

for protein_id, domain_id, entry in domains.items():
    row = Domain.objects.create(
        pfam=pfam_rows[domain_id],
        description=entry[1],
        start=entry[2],
        stop=entry[3]
    )
    row.protein.add(proteins_rows[protein_id])
    row.save()
```

I left code where I am ok beyond my question. My question concerns the last block, where I am creating Domain table and adding protein row to linking table, in my case I got an error:

> for protein_id, domain_id, entry in domains.items():
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2).

I tried to use dictionary for my domains. like this:

```
domains = defaultdict(dict)
```

and construct the dict like this:

```
domains[row[0].strip()][row[5]] = row[4:5]+row[6:8],
```

but it does not work either.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Couple of Django tips:

* No need of a `row.save()` after a `row = Model.objects.create()` call

* If you don't define the `ProteinDomainLink` model, Django will auto-generate it for you. It can then be accessed as `Domain.protein.through` and as `Protein.domains.through`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Error is:

for protein_id, domain_id, entry in domains.items(): ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is not related to Django ORM, it's caused by trying to unpack two values into three variables:

```
for protein_id, domain_id, entry in domains.items():
```

`domains.items()` is a collection of `(key, list_of_something)` pairs and has to be unpacked in two variables, like:

```
for protein_id, entry in domains.items():
```

If needed, the `entry` list can then be iterated in a nested loop:

```
# 'entry' is not a great name here. Using it just for consistency with the original code
for protein_id, entry in domains.items():
    for item in entry:
        <do_something>
```

Comment: Ok, great, thank you, but how to iterate then in a nested loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: should I use dict: 
domains = defaultdict(dict)

and domans like:
domains[row[0].strip()][row[5]] = row[4:5]+row[6:8] ?

Comment: You should use whatever data structure allows you to best represent your data. With a dict you'd need a nested `for`-loop as well

Comment: for protein_id, entry in domains.items():
    for domain_id in entry:
        row = Domain.objects.create(
            pfam=pfam_rows[domain_id],
            # description=entry[0],
            # start=entry[1],
            # stop=entry[2]
        )
    row.protein.add(proteins_rows[protein_id])
    row.save()

Better, but still goes incorrect, the result in linking table looks like:  

  id   | domain_id | protein_id 
-------+-----------+------------
 34878 |     49607 |     199768
34879 |     49608 |     199769


It just iterates one by one my lists - domain and protein.

Comment: Am I right with that:

for protein_id, entry in domains.items():
    for domain_id in entry:

?